# define specific cell in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found the below JavaScript code and I really need it but with some changes.
*this link* **[Sending emails from a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)**

let see the problem here:

```
var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
```

Now I'm trying to make script send an email mail defined by cell **A2** not all emails in `row[0]`.
Then the script *delays 1 minute* or any thing and goes to send next **A3** and *loop*

Comment: Sorry but the question isn't very clear. You want to send an email to a recipient defined in A2, correct? What should happen after that? is that all or do you want to send an email to a recipient defined in A3 as well?

Comment: It sounds like you want to send an email to an address in A2 and then one to an address in A3 but that's exactly what the script in the sample is already doing. Or do you **not** want it to send an email to a recipient in A3?

Comment: ok ..
the script really send mails but all mails (as one) i want from script send mail from A2 and wait "delay any time" before send next mail .

Comment: do you understand me now @RobinGertenbach ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Apps script has a [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/) class, which among other things provides a [sleep](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) method.

To have the script for a minute before sending an email to the next recipient try inserting `Utilities.sleep(60000)`, to have it sleep for 60k milliseconds to have it wait for one minute.
Insert this in the row directly following the call to `MailApp.sendEmail` before the closing bracket.

Be aware that [there is a limit on how long scripts can run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) (6 minutes) and sleeping counts towards that.

Comment: ok it work , thankx / but send 2 mails and stop do you have idea ?

Comment: So you want to send only to the recipients in the first two rows?

Comment: no after edit script send 2 mail A2 and A3 then stop .
i want continuing
Why he stop after 2mail
Note : i am setting sleep 30000

Comment: see image here 
**[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94MHoO2AK6UNXVtRVZMeU9KS1k/view)**

Comment: `numRows` is set to 2 in the example, do you still have that? Instead of `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)` try `var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()`

Comment: ok thanks it's run wonderful 
I am appreciate for you help Mr.Robin